# Laravel4 raw statement in the middle of complex where

Tags: laravel

I have a quite complex `search` method which handles the `$input` array from a controller, the thing is that I want to perform a custom SQL statement in the middle of it, for example:

```
$input['myField'] = array('condition' => 'rawStatement', value => 'AND WHERE LEFT(field,9) = 10`
```

and that would apply into my busy-conditions-method-builder

You can see the method at
http://pastebin.com/BNUKk2Xd

I'm trying to apply it on lines 52-54 but cant seem to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but looking at your pastbin you have to chain your query like.

```
$query = User::join('user_personal','users.id','=','user_personal.user_id');

# Join user askings
$query = $query->leftJoin('user_askings','users.id','=','user_askings.user_id');

$query = ..........

$query = $query->orderBy('users.profile_score','DESC');
$query = $query->groupBy('users.id')->paginate(32);

return $query;
```